# How to fix this error in pandas datafrom - KeyError: 'Zone% (pfx)'

Tags: pandas, keyerror

I am trying to do a simple dataframe on pybaseball package. This was all working until this week 28/3/2021.  But now I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Zone% (pfx)'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Zone% (pfx)'
```

Here is the code that I have run:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

pd.set_option('chained_assignment', None)

%pip install pybaseball==2.0.0

import pybaseball as pyb

df_2020 = pyb.batting_stats(2020)
```

This is being run in google colab.

Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've find a solution but I see they've released a new pybaseball, version 2.2.0 which doesn't seem to throw anymore errors